# C# Components won't show after calling class

Tags: c#

I honestly don't know how my components won't show.

basically this is my structure:

[image]

and right now i am building a 'thread' which is one of the 'name here' this will be a message preview .....' 
all i am asking is this: can someone lead me in the right direction. I am a java developer and getting used to c#

```
MessageThread m = new MessageThread("Example Name", "Hey man, How are you?", "12:34", "000000000325");
m.buildThread();
```

and here is this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace FacebookMessenger
{
    class MessageThread
    {
        private String title;
        private String preview;
        private String time;
        private String userId;
        public Label lblTitle = new Label();

        public MessageThread(String title, String preview, String time, String userId)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.preview = preview;
            this.time = time;
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public void buildThread()
        {
            lblTitle.Content = "Name Here";
            lblTitle.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Light");
            lblTitle.FontSize = 28;
            lblTitle.Width = 400;
            lblTitle.Height = 50;
            lblTitle.Foreground = Brushes.Wheat;
        }
    }
}
```

it would be really helpful if someone helped me out thanks.

Comment: I assume you are aware that manipulating the UI outside the UI thread is prohibited in both Java and C#.

Comment: You can do it in Java by making the ui public and static.

http://i.imgur.com/cTt1jbh.png
http://i.imgur.com/bFMqEtX.png

Comment: For Java, can you refer me to an article that indicates that manipulating public static UI elements outside the UI thread is safe?

Comment: The fact that it works in a particular case does not mean it always will.

Comment: Well how do people build messenger apps? Do they just appear without changing ui?

Comment: In Java you call SwingUtilities.invokeLater from any thread that is not the EDT.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Win Forms you need to update the labels on the UI thread, i.e,

```
        private void UpdateTitle(string newTitle)
        {         
            if (this.lblTitle.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.lblTitle.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() { this.lblTitle.Text = newTitle; });    
            }
            else
            {
                this.lblTitle.Text = newTitle;
            }
        }
```

If you're using WPF you should bind the labels to a view model and use [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when the UI needs to be refreshed.